# compatibility of windows phone 7 applications with windows 8 OS

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a windows phone 7 application and as we know Windows 8 will have metro UI.

will WP7 applications be compatible with windows 8 desktop OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly. It is a different stack from WP7's Silverlight. Windows 8 Metro applications use something new called WinRT. You might be able to reuse some code and XAML, provided you design it appropriately.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide me some links for WinRT.

Comment: Here is a great one to get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/

Comment: Visit http://www.buildwindows.com/ to know all about development for Windows 8. Also take a look at [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VS11TrainingCourse_PortableLibraries) to share code between WP7 and Win8.

Answer (score 2):

If you use MVVM, you could theoretically reuse your complete business logic, all view models, all services. The XAML Ui would have to be reimplemented anyway, as phone and win8 look pretty different.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight is not available in windows 8. so you will need to find a counterpart of the silverlight libraries. The good thing is the replacement are available.
check this link for porting wp7 application to window 8
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465136%28v=VS.85%29.aspx